# Проигрывание списка треков, с возможностью остановки/повторного запуска проигрывания/остановки играющего и одновременного запуска нового трека

Tags: javascript, html, api

Ув.знатоки! Передо мной нерушимо стала проблема реализации проигрывания списка треков по клику. Сразу оговорюсь - я новичек, посему не удивляйтесь моим возможным костылям.
Огромное количество времени я потратил на то, что бы сделать так, что бы при нажатии на любой трек-ссылку, играющий трек останавливался и тут же запускался тот, по которому был произведен клик. Увы, я не преуспел. На данном этапе мне нужно сначала остановить текущий трек и только потом я смогу запустить любой другой. Уповаю на помощь просветленных в этом вопросе.
Вот мой код:

```js
var musicLinksArr = [
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952238/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952236/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952235/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952230/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952227/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952225/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952223/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175412/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175410/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175407/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175405/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175403/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175399/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175395/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb"
];
var musicStream = new Audio();

$(".tracks-list ul li div a").on("click", function() {
  var selectorId = this.id;
  var numberFilter = /\d+/g;
  var trackIndex = selectorId.match(numberFilter);

  if (musicStream.paused === true) {
    let currentTrack = trackIndex;
    musicStream.src = musicLinksArr[currentTrack];
    musicStream.play();
  } else {
    musicStream.pause();
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tracks-list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#n0" class="track" id="musicPlay0">From Sorrow To Joy</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#n1" class="track" id="musicPlay1">Higfly</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#n2" class="track" id="musicPlay2">Not Forget</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#n3" class="track" id="musicPlay3">Fall Of Phaeton</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#n4" class="track" id="musicPlay4">Prevaling Sense</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#n5" class="track" id="musicPlay5">Tender Sense</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#n6" class="track" id="musicPlay6">Desperate Sense</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Ccылка на Пэн c данным примером:
https://codepen.io/Metalspell/pen/rojroO

Comment: Чесно говоря, толком не понял, что означает **с возможностью остановки/повторного запуска проигрывания/остановки играющего и одновременного запуска нового трека**? А главное, должен ли быть предусмотрен случай одновременного воспроизведения больше, чем одного трека? Если нет, то лучше тогда на странице использовать только один элемент аудио, а при клике на соответствующий трек только задавать ему новый **src** и по-новой запускать. Если интересует такой вариант, могу написать в ответе.

Comment: Постараюсь изъясниться более развернуто. Возможность одновременного проигрывания более одного трека исключена. Предполагается возможность запуска одного трека по клику и его же остановку по повторному клику по нему же. Во время проигрывания определенного трека, при клике по другому, текущее проигрывание должно остановится, а трек, по которому произведен клик - запуститься.

Comment: С большим удовольствием взглянул бы на предложенную вами реализацию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не надо использовать тег `<a></a>` где попало и как попало. Это ссылка и используй ее как ссылку.

Извини не люблю `JQ`, ответ на обычном `JS`.

Далее в комментариях в коде опишу что к чему.

```js
//======добавляем удаляем класс чтобы видеть который играет == начало

function changeClass(elem) {
  return elem.classList.contains('active') ? elem.classList.remove('active') : elem.classList.add('active');
}

function removeClass(elem) {
  for (let index of elem) {
    index.classList.remove('active')
  }
}
//=================  конец  ===================

var musicLinksArr = [
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952238/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952236/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952235/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952230/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952227/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952225/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/316952223/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175412/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175410/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175407/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175405/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175403/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175399/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb",
  "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175395/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb"
];


const musicStream = new Audio();
// можно не писать кучу  элементов в html, а просто 
// создать один и потом клонировать его.

let elem = document.createElement('li');

// На основе количества трекков (массив musicLinksArr) 
// мы клонируем тот самый созданный элемент (elem)

musicLinksArr.forEach((s, i) => {
  let trecks = elem.cloneNode(true);
  trecks.classList.add('trecks');
  trecks.innerHTML = 'Trecks' + i;
  document.querySelector('.tracks-list ul').appendChild(trecks);
})

const button = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

li.forEach((s, i) => {
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {

    if (musicStream.src !== musicLinksArr[i] && musicStream.paused) {
      // условие если дорожки не идентичны и муз не играет ===== 
      musicStream.src = musicLinksArr[i];
      musicStream.play();
      changeClass(s);
      console.log('Первый раз');
      //===========================================

    } else if (musicStream.src === musicLinksArr[i] && !musicStream.paused) {
      // условие, если дорожки идентичны и муз играет ===== 
      musicStream.pause();
      changeClass(s)
      console.log('Пауза');
      //===========================================

    } else if (musicStream.src === musicLinksArr[i] && musicStream.paused) {
      // условие, если дорожки идентичны и муз не играет ===== 
      musicStream.play();
      changeClass(s)
      console.log('После паузы');
      //===========================================

    } else if (musicStream.src !== musicLinksArr[i] && !musicStream.paused) {
      // условие, если дорожки не идентичны и муз  играет =====
      removeClass(li);
      musicStream.src = musicLinksArr[i];
      musicStream.play();
      changeClass(s)
      console.log('Новый трек');
      //===========================================
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.tracks {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="tracks-list">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Arthur, Благодарю...

Comment: всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: Спасибо за уделенное внимание. Проглядев ваш код, я, увы, так и не понял, как мне его допилить, дабы я мог останавливать проигрывание (стоп/пауза) Касательно тега ссылки - учту)

Comment: Ты объясни как ты хочешь выключать или поставить на паузу...

Comment: Уточню - выключать

Comment: Изменил ответ...

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score 0):

Реализация с одним элементом аудио:

```html
<style>
li:hover{
    width: 100px;
    background: gold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<audio id=audio src="sound1.mp3" controls></audio>
<ul>
    <li id="sound1.mp3">sound1</li>
    <li id="sound2.mp3">sound2</li>
    <li id="sound3.mp3">sound3</li>
    <li id="sound4.mp3">sound4</li>
    <li id="sound5.mp3">sound5</li>
</ul>
<script>
var last = "";
var alles_li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i = 0; i < alles_li.length; i++){
    alles_li[i].onclick = function(){
  if(this.id != last)audio.src = last = this.id;
  if(audio.paused){audio.play()}else{audio.pause()};
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: У меня код вообще не функционирует.

Comment: я загнал этот вариант на хостинг, вот [ссылка](http://opan.strana.de/muzik/mp3/playlist.html) На примере **sonnd2** можно посмотреть, как это работает. Если бы всё было нормально, с этим кодом не должно быть проблем, но видимо сейчас пошли какие-то нестабильные браузеры, и помимо отсутствия автовоспроищведения ещё когда хотят обнаруживают подключаемый аудиофайл, в остальных случаях за неизвестных причин нет.

Comment: Поэтому sound1, 3 и 4 вызывают ошибку **Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found** не смотря на то, что ни в коде ошибок нет, и все аудиофайлы полноценные. В то же время на локалке у меня это всё работает чётко.